# How to exclude already existing items from dropdownlist? The values are populated based on some condition in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list

In my web application project I have a LinkButton and when clicking it a popup page  AddControlsPopup.aspx will come .

On this page I have to fill ddlValues Dropdownlist from xml with some condition.

The First Dropdownlist is ddlValues. Initially the dropdownlist is populated with all data.

The second Dropdownlist is ddlControlType

Third Dropdownlist  is ddlConditionControl.

In the popup page there exists a button to add the controls , need to select values from these 3 dropdownlist.

After clicking the Button, the 3 dropdownlist values added to Xml Controls section.

In the page there exist a button to add the controls. It will be saved to xml.

This is the process.

**My doubt is that after adding all the combination of ControlValue, ControlType and ConditionControl, I have to exclude the ControlValue from the First dropdownlist ddlValues**

Pls help

I have an XML File with the following data.

```
< ControlSet>

< Control>

< Values>

< ValueID>1< /ValueID>

< ValueName> ABC < /ValueName>

< /Values>

< Values>

< ValueID>2< /ValueID>

< ValueName> DEF< /ValueName>

< /Values>

< Values>

< ValueID>3< /ValueID>

< ValueName> XYZ< /ValueName>

< /Values>

< Controls>

< ControlValues>

< ValueID>1 </ValueID>

< ControlTypeID>1 < /ControlTypeID>

< ConditonControlID> 1 < /ConditionControlID>

< /ControlValues>

< ControlValues>

< ValueID>1 </ValueID>

< ControlTypeID>1 < /ControlTypeID>

< ConditonControlID> 2 < /ConditionControlID>

< /ControlValues>

< ControlValues>

< ValueID>1 </ValueID>

< ControlTypeID>2 < /ControlTypeID>

< ConditonControlID> 1 < /ConditionControlID>

< /ControlValues>
```

Comment: please highlight text that you want to remove from xml.